# Creating a multivariate distributed matrix in python?

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, scipy

I have two problems.

1). First: How to generate a 1000x100 dim matrix each dimension being a marginal distribution with mean 0 and 1?. I know I can use univariate diet for each but how do you add 100 such distribution in one numpy/ pandas matrix?

2). Generate a 100x1000 dim matrix . This would use a multivariate dist, but how do you specify the mean and covariant matrix for that numpy function. It has to be random.

Comment: It is unclear to me what your question is about, what is "marginal diet" and "diet"? Look at [scipy stats package](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html) if your want to generate statistical distributions with different shapes.

Comment: Sorry for typo. I meant marginal distribution. I have checked numpy methods. Problem is if I want to have a multivariate distribution it would require me to pass a mean vector and a covariance matrix. Now I am not sure how do you provide a random or create a covariance matrix for such high dimension. Also, if I want to have a multivariate distribution with each co-ordinate generated from a marginal dist. probability function, how you do that?